# How do I randomly select in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I wanna randomly select 1 by 6 matrix elements between -1 and 1.

For example, `[-1 1 -1 1 1 1]`

How do I select it??

Comment: It says it all here http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/random.html

Answer (score 2):

Create a vector of possible values, and use `randi` to generate random indices into that vector.

```
Choices = [-1 1];
Index = randi(length(Choices), 1, 6);
Choices(Index)
ans =

     1     1     1    -1     1    -1
```

Comment: Read up on random numbers in matlab; you'll need to seed the random number generator if you need it to be different every time you start up the program.

Comment: +1! I have always used a combination of `round` and `rand` for this type of thing in the past, but this is much better!

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of completeness:

```
randVec = 2*randi([0 1], 1,6) - 1;
```